# I cannot prevent mousewheel event in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I want to prevent the user from scrolling via mouse wheel. In Firefox it works but not in Chrome. What must be changed for Chrome?

```
$(window).on('wheel', function(e) {    
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent user scroll during page jump
})
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tewfzgj6/)

Comment: As a user, please don't do this. For whatever reason you feel the need for this, I can guarantee you it's a terrible thing to be doing for UX.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the website needs a sroll to section functionality, that's why

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a reason to completely stop the scrollwheel from working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the event handler to non-passive for it to work on Chrome. That is not possible in jQuery as far as I know. But you can use the regular `addEventListener` for this.

```js
document.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent user scroll during page jump
}, {
  passive: false
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Mousewheel should be prevented</p>
</div>
```

As pointed out by [Shikkediel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3168107/shikkediel) in the comments: if you want to support older (versions of) browsers (for example Internet Explorer), it is recommended to first check if the `passive` option is supported by the browser. Older browsers had a boolean type as the third parameter of the `addEventListener`. Therefore they might throw an error, or they could set the third parameter to true (default is false) which might cause some undesired behavior. You can use the code below for that.

```js
var passiveSupported = supportsPassive();

document.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent user scroll during page jump
}, passiveSupported ? {
  passive: false
} : false);

function supportsPassive() {
  var passiveSupported = false;

  try {
    var options = {
      get passive() {
        passiveSupported = true;
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("test", options, options);
    window.removeEventListener("test", options, options);
  } catch (err) {
    passiveSupported = false;
  }

  return passiveSupported;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Mousewheel should be prevented</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Recommended to add [feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Safely_detecting_option_support) if you want to [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=passive-event-listener) IE.